# compress: No compression -- file unchanged

Tags: compression

I was trying to compress an image on Linux, specifically using the `compress` command, and it wasn't working. Can you please advise, based on the output below, what I'm doing wrong and how I could fix it in order to compress using specifically that method?

Thanks so much

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# compress -v Engineers.png Engineers.png2
Engineers.png: No compression -- Engineers.png unchanged
Engineers.png2: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Unix Stackexchange! While EduardoTrápani has very nicely answered what you asked, I don't think using the compress program is a good idea in the first place. It is an archaic program, and it's not as efficient. It only serves the purpose if you would exchange data with legacy computers from the last century. The more popular program is gzip, practically every distro ships it now. And there is also zstd, which is new technology and has best performance, but it's not widely adopted yet.

Answer (score 3):

> Can you please advise, based on the output below, what i am doing wrong and how i could fix it in order to compress using specifically that method?

The png image is already compressed. `compress` checks that and, given that it cannot reduce the size of the picture, it leaves the file unchanged.

I you really want to force `compress` to do the compression, you can do this:

```
$ compress -vf Engineers.png
```

Note that the output will have a negative compression, to indicate how much bigger the "compressed" version is in relationship with the original.